# How To Boot XEN VMs Using iSCSI?

Tags: boot, virtualization, xen, iscsi

In simple, I want **boot XEN fully virtualized (HVM) guests** (both *Windows* & *Linux*) using **iSCSI drives** (i.e. *from SAN*).

My **main purpose of this is to learn** about this process. So, how can I do it? How to setup VM / VM config file so that it supports booting from iSCSI??

Comment: P.S.: I am using XEN hypervisor 4.0 and LVM based HVM guests are running without any problem (has locally attached storage)

Comment: I just finished a blog entry on how to boot the Xen hypervisor (not just the DomU) using gPXE. You can adapt this method to boot anything, including a DomU (though you could just store the DomU virtual disks on a remote iSCSI LUN or NFS server). See: http://sporadicblogging.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/diskless-oracle-virtual-machines-with-ovm-3-0-2/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this like a virtualization problem doesn't help. Ask yourself, how would I boot from iSCSI in the real world? The answer is you need an iSCSI initiator. Virtualization isn't magic, it emulates a common computer with common peripherals, you can add new peripherals, albeit virtual ones, just like could in the real world. In this case the [gPXE project](http://etherboot.org/wiki/start) provides an option rom that can be fed to QEMU to add the additional ability of an iSCSI initiator. Everything else is an exercise for the reader. Good luck!